# Font of OOF Replies

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

I am currently developing an Add-In for Outlook. This Add-In edits the OOF Settings of the logged in Outlook user. I have to take the text for the external  message from a .oft File.
The Add-In is running fine and everything's working as intended. There is just this one little issue with the font. I would like to change the font of both replies to our company standard but i see no way of implementing that.

Is there a way of changing the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help!
The simplest way was to just add the html tags to the string which I use for the `OofReply`-object. Like so: `string message = "<html><div style='font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri;'>" + template.body + "</div></html>";`

Answer (score 2):

Body.Html allows you to specify a coercion type.  Here you can specify HTML and add style to the text in the body.
For Example:

```html
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(
  "<p style=\"font-family: 'Arial Black', 'Arial Bold', Gadget, sans-serif;\">text</p>",
  { coercionType:"html"},
  function callback(result) {
    // Process the result
  });
```

For reference: https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Body.html

Answer (score 1):

You could Get the item you want to alter, and then Update it, as [outlined here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535506(v=exchg.150).aspx). What you will need to do is get the `Body`-property of the mail, and then alter the `<body>`-tag in this Body:

```
// As a best practice, limit the properties returned to only those that are required.
PropertySet propSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.Body);

// Bind to the existing item by using the ItemId.
// This method call results in a GetItem call to EWS.
Item item = Item.Bind(service, itemId, propSet);

// item.Body.value = "<html><body> Example body </body></html>"

// Update the style of the mail's body.
item.Body.value = "<html><body style='font-family: Arial'> Example body </body></html>"

// Save the updated email.
// This method call results in an UpdateItem call to EWS.
item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
```